# lottie-react-native requires a peer of react@* but none is installed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a project where `lottie-react-native` package is being used. I have cloned the code to a new machine now and not able to clean resolve the dependent module.

I tried deleting `node_module` directory from the project and reinstalled the modules and linked. 
Didn't work.

Any other way to fix this?

Comment: Did you run react-native-link after installing the module?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Before moving the code, create a new project, install the module, run the link, and run the project. Move the code in case there is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the problem with `lottie` package and seems not yet fixed.

Managed to change the gradle properties of lottie to below form and repeated the npm install, react-native link. Worked like a charm.

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.6'
    api("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0")
}
```